# When Using Immersive Mode a line appears

Tags: android, fullscreen, android-4.4-kitkat

I'm trying to use the immersive mode introduced in Android 4.4. I use this code to set the visibility and it works exactly how I want it to:

```
View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();

                    int uiOptions = //View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION // hide nav bar
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN // hide status bar
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY;


                    decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
```

However, it puts a line on the display. I have a screenshot but cannot post it because this is my first question. I have no idea what it is or how to get rid of it. Can anyone help?